# VS2012 IIS Express Option Disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have just installed VS2012 and created a MVC project. I right clicked on project and selected property, I chose Web tab. I selected "Use Local IIS Web server" but the "Use IIS Express" checkbox is disabled.

I checked my `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\` folder and IIS Express 8 is there.

Any particular reason?

---

If I fall back to use Visual Studio Development Server, I have 50% of the chance to see "Server Too Busy" message.

Comment: I'm seeing similar behaviour, though the "Use IIS Express" checkbox is pre-checked, so that If I select "Use Local IIS Web server" I have no other options. I don't have full IIS installed on this machine (Win8) so I assume that's why. What OS are you running? Do you also have VS2010 SP1 installed?

Answer (score 7):

All you have to do is to activate IIS in your development machine:

Start -> Control Panel -> Enable or disable Windows features -> Internet Services

Then check mark in World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP Features

And check mark  in World Wide Web Services -> Application development Features

That's all you need.

Comment: You have not a third option with Microsoft, you have to choose between IIS or IIS Express, in case where full IIS is not installed on your development machine, the unique remaining choice is IIS Express, that's why the IIS Express check box in Visual Studio project property is check marked and greyed.

Answer (score 1):

Using Full IIS has some benefits.  One is that it is always running, so you don't have to start your VStudio Project to unit test.  Another is that you can create an actual site and configure IIS mirroring production, using the same Admin Tools, which makes it easier to support when deployed in an environment.  And, I seem to recall that IISExpress had issues with Application Routing.  On the flip side, I don't see an issue with using the Full IIS.  Granted, IISExpress is much better than Cassini, but if there is no reason to not use Full IIS then I conitnue to advocate it's use.

Comment: There's another really compelling reason to use a full IIS and not IIS Express - if you are developing 64-bit assemblies, the stock IIS express will not be able to load them.

Comment: To run Full IIS you need admin rights. Not every dev get that ;-)